# Denoise and reduce JPEG artifacts from a grayscale historical document on microfilm (Adobe CC preferred)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would very much appreciate your thoughts on how to improve 600 images that look [exactly like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dd8di7DxUyveDLZLDpJx-P9BuD9lPPTo/view?usp=sharing).

The end-goal is to upload these images as a book to the Internet Archive (archive .org).  These images have already been worked on as 600 separate PhotoShop jobs (each of which, I have saved).  All I have done, thus far, is to de-warp each image using PhotoShop's perspective crop feature, then manually adjust levels for each image.

The images themselves were captured by camera in 1953 under varying light conditions.  This was done to produce a microfilm duplicate.  A scan of that microfilm--which involves two pages of the opened book per slide--is the source for each image.  Unfortunately, the digital files I have, for each page, are HIGHLY compressed JPEG from the scan of the microfilm duplicate (I think each download was around 1.2 MB per slide (with two pages on it)).

I could really use some ideas on how to make these pages look as legible and "pleasing to the eye."  My goal is not for the pages to reproduce with any authenticity to the original document.  I intend this to be a workhorse for historical researchers, so legibility is key---but if the digital artifacts could be smoothed out, etc, I'd be grateful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPG artifacts are there to stay. Smoothing them for ex. with Photoshop's own noise reduction filter or tresholded "Smart" Blur makes the letters more blurry. Only a highly intelligent cleaning program which knows what's writing or at least an intended line in the middle of nearly as high contrast grains can decide the right originals behind the artifacts.

Increase the contrast with an adjustment layer. Add a curves layer. Find a good smooth curve which lifts the paper to less dark and makes dark grey more close to black, but doesn't fade the finest squiggles of the writing. Spray with a big smooth low opacity brush black to the layer mask of the adjustment layer on those areas which are originally dark - here the bottom edge.

[image]

Here's the same the adjustment layer closed:

[image]

Do not expect any tresholding is useful, only smooth curve can keep enough information and improve the readability.

If you are lucky one found good mask and good curve are good for several pages. As I said: If you are lucky.

One possibility to get rid of the page dependent mask is to reduce large scale luminosity differences, but keep the local contrast:

[image]

On the top there's the curves adjustment layer for best general contrast. In the middle there's a copy of the text layer, but its blending mode is Hard Light. In addition the layer has got Filter > Other > Highpass > about 50 pixels. The filtering keeps the letters and all trash but remove smooth brightness variations. You must experiment for the good filtering radius.

The advantage got by these filterings is small. Try few pages and check is the result worth the effort.

If you find that a certain filtering and curve fits well for a big bunch of pages prepare an action for automation.

**ADD:** I red in a comment that a Topaz noise reduction utility achieved useful cleaning without fading text too much. Just for curiosity I tried to filter the image with Redfield Perfectum denoiser plugin.It had earlier shown some cleverness to see what's intended squiggle and what's random graininess.

It took off the finest grain. After the filtering the image gotthe same treatment (=a copy with highpass filtering + blending mode hard light, on the top curves layer) It looks cleaner, but you should decide does it help reading:

[image]

Unfortunately Perfectum also costs money, but not as much as Topaz stuff. I have tried some Topaz plugins and results with them make me suspect that the price difference gives more than only plain air.

Comment: This is extremely helpful!  I really appreciate your time. I'm a little terrified to hear your (or someone's) answer on a quick follow-up question: was I doing the levels-adjustment process correct in the first place?  Here is a little folder with how I've been doing that, and a before and after image: https://bit.ly/3tjCj7F    (I'm a total newbie with photoshop, obviously ;).  Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @Ryan Levels adjustment in this jobis a reduced version of what curves can do. But I guess it's as useful as the curves because a smooth monotonic remapping is wanted. You meet the same large area light difference problem as well with Levels and Curves. It's up to you decide iif the result of levels adjustment is better for your reading than the original was.As I said, it cannot do more than curves but there's less possibilities to weird settings.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop CC 2021 has a JPEG Artefacts Removal neural filter. Perhaps give that a go. It's not fast, as the processing is done in the cloud. So, Photoshop first has to upload the image, and then download the result. Each image will likely take several minutes depending on your internet speed.

[image]

Here's a screen shot at 100%. I'll let you decide if there's enough improvement to make it worthwhile.

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned this in OP (my bad!).  It's unquestionably a nifty filter but also impractical due to time it takes, and CPU burden (i7 MacBook Pro 2.6 Ghz 16 GB RAM).  CPU was cooking and whole process took a minute or more to process one image (I have 594).  I think @user287001 is pretty spot on in that the JPEG artifacts are there to stay. The GOOD news is that just a manual (page-by-page) levels adjustment has revealed new information that wasn't apparent to the naked eye beforehand.  TY again nevertheless!

Comment: I should mention, I also played around with a standalone AI-powered de-noiser earlier today, produced by Topaz Labs.  I was surprised by both the results and the size of the app, which looks like it should be a 20MB to download, by appearance, but is actually well over a GB. (the results were quite good, but it was much more than I was willing to spend, to remove the watermarks and own a license).

Comment: @Ryan You might want to have a look at the denoise capabilities in Adobe Camera RAW, or perhaps Adobe Lightroom Classic which are both very good for quickly denoising photographs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give [jpegneo](https://jpegneo.com) plugin a shot.  It tries to reduce JPEG artifacts on import by tweaking the coefficients.

It works better for cases where it's blocky, but it might help with your case too.  Likely it would still need more processing, but you would start off from a higher quality image after decompression.